# About the category $\mathbf{Coh}(\mathbb{P}^2,\mathcal{B}_0)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories

In the paper [*A Categorical Invariant for Cubic Threefolds*](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2011.10.007), Bernardara, Macrì, Mehrotra, and Stellari consider the category $\mathbf{Coh}(\mathbb{P}^2,\mathcal{B}_0)$ where $\mathcal{B}_0$ is a rank $4$ locally free sheaf over $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}$ as well as the even part of the Clifford algebra of a quadric fibration over $\mathbb{P}^2$.

The category has different names in that paper:

- sheaves on $\mathbb{P}^2$ with an action of the algebra $\mathcal{B}_0$
- coherent sheaves of $\mathcal{B}_0$-algebras on $\mathbb{P}^2$
- right coherent $\mathcal{B}_0$-modules on $\mathbb{P}^2$.

I wonder if they are the same thing. Moreover, my main question is why the sheaves in $\mathbf{Coh}(\mathbb{P}^2,\mathcal{B}_0)$ have rank a multiple of $4$ as a $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}$-module (c.f. page 782 in that paper).

I did not really get the point. Locally speaking, $A\times 0$ is a $A\times B$ for any rings $A$, $B$. What will prevent $A\times0$ from being a coherent $A\times B$-module?

Comment: What does "$A \times 0$ is a $A \times B$" mean?  Should it be "… is an $A \times B$-module"?

Answer (score 4):

The rank is defined generically, so we may restrict to the general point of the projective plane. Thus, we may consider the field $K$ of rational functions on $\mathbb{P}^2$, then the general fiber of $\mathcal{B}_0$ is a central simple algebra $B_0$ of rank 4 over $K$.

Assume $M$ is a $B_0$-module. Since
$$
B_0 \otimes_K \bar{K} \cong \mathrm{Mat}_2(\bar{K}),
$$
the $K$-dimension of any $B_0$-module is divisible by $2$.
Now, if $M$ is a 2-dimensional $B_0$-module, the morphism
$$
B_0 \to \mathrm{End}_K(M) 
$$
induced by the $B_0$-action is a homomorphism of algebras, hence its kernel is trivial (because $B_0$ is simple), and since the dimensions of the source and target are both 4, it is an isomorphism. This means that $B_0$ is a matrix algebra. But it is proved in the paper that it is not.